# Link custom post type category to anchor on same page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, drop-down-menu, filter

I'm trying to make a dropdown list work as a filter on a page.  I have created the form, and the anchors are there, just nothing is happening when you click on the drop down item.  How do I trigger it linking to an anchor?

Here's the jQuery I was using:

```
<script>
$("#portfolio-list").bind("change", function() {
    $("#" + this.value).show();
    $("p:not(#" + this.value + ")").hide();
});</script>
```

Here is my form:

```
<form name="dropdown" size="1" id="portfolio-list">
<select name="portfolio-list" id="portfolio-list">
<option value="#" rel="all" class="current">All</option> 
<option value="#custom-exhibits" rel=custom-exhibits class=custom-exhibits>Custom Exhibits</option>
<option value="#permanent-installation" rel=permanent-installation class=permanent-installation>Permanent Installation</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted has nothing to do with 'anchors', which I assume refers to `<a>` tags.

Remember: jQuery selectors are based on CSS selectors. A leading `.` matches elements with that `class`, a leading `#` matches the element with that `id`.

The first line of the event handler will show the element whose `id` matches `this.value`. The second line will hide all `<p>` whose `id` does not match `this.value`. (BTW, jQuery provides a [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function that is a bit easier to read)

An important bug: your `option`s `value`s all start with `#`, then the script concats `#` in front of it again. This is probably not what you want.

Side note: ["As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers"](http://api.jquery.com/bind/). Not that `.bind()` doesn't work, but `.on()` is shorter and more featureful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a working example from code you posted.

The first thing I noticed is that both, the form and select tags have the same id attribute ( id value must be unique within the HTML document ), that’s why `"#portfolio-list"` selector don't work as expected, `change` event is triggered for the form and not for the select tag (if you are not sending data back to the server the form tag is not needed ).

Furthermore, selectors for paragraps like `"#"+this.value` are starting with #, and options values start with # also, at the end the selector looks like `"##custom-exhibits`, and that is not a valid selector.

In jQuery the `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements, `.value` is native JavaScript and although both methods are correct, if you are using jQuery then it is better to use his methods.

```
<select name="portfolio-list" id="portfolio-list">
    <option value="all" rel="all" class="current">All</option> 
    <option value="custom-exhibits" rel="custom-exhibits" class="custom-exhibits">Custom Exhibits</option>
    <option value="permanent-installation" rel="permanent-installation" class="permanent-installation">Permanent Installation</option>
</select>

<p id="all" >paragraph1</p>
<p id="custom-exhibits" >paragraph2</p>
<p id="permanent-installation" >paragraph3</p>

<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#portfolio-list").on( 'change', function(e) {
        // get selected option value
        var val = $(this).val();
        // show element with that id
        $( '#'+val ).show();
        // hide all other elements
        $('p').not( '#'+val ).hide();
    });
});
</script>
```